# PopoverClasses property in Menu element in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I previous (v4) I used `makeStyle` to pass class to `PopoverClasses` property in  element.

How to fill this prop in v5 version where `makeStyles` is obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PopoverClasses` prop from [`Menu`](https://mui.com/api/menu/) is used to [inject](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/742ed168f8d920069bbc1dbaa38b41a86eb0a484/packages/mui-material/src/Menu/Menu.js#L161-L161) the class names to the `Popover` component, whose `classes` prop has these [CSS properties](https://mui.com/api/popover/#css) that can be overridden. You can do the same in **MUI v5** by getting the `popoverClasses` from the `Popover` and apply to the `Popover` component like this:

```
import { popoverClasses } from "@mui/material/Popover";
```

```
<Menu
  sx={{
    [`&.${popoverClasses.root}`]: {
      backgroundColor: "gray"
    },
    [`& .${popoverClasses.paper}`]: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  }}
  {...}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]